# Number is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just recently starter to follow a tutorial on Android Studio programming. It's been going well until I got stuck on following error:

```
Number is abstract; cannot be instantiated.
```

The code works for the guy in the tutorial. (He has older version of Android Studio 2.2.0.12.) My version is 3.5.1.

```
public void testNumber(View view) {
    EditText userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNumber);
    Number myNumber = new Number(); /* stuck at this part*/
    myNumber.number = Integer.parseInt(userNumber.getText().toString());
    System.out.println(myNumber.isTriangular());
    System.out.println(myNumber.isSquare());
```

Comment: ***public abstract class Number implements Serializable {***... that means you can not just do Number x  = new Number

Comment: Given that `isTriangular` and `isSquare` aren't part of `java.lang.Number`, it sounds like you've got a separate `Number` class somewhere. I'd strongly advise you to rename that to avoid these issues.

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial? As far as I know Number has always been abstract in the JDK, so he might be using a different class.

Comment: Can you show your import of the Number class.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are classes that cannot be instantiated. They only serve as a "mother" class for other non-abstract classes. Number class is probably "mother" class for Integer, Decimal or something like that.

Now, if you are following a tutorial and it tells you to create a class named Number, then the problem is that this class is getting mixed up with java.lang.Number class. If you have a tutorial that tells you to instantiate java.lang.Number, then tutorial is either outdated or plain wrong.

But I think you are gonna use Number as a container for any "child" class of Number (like you are doing in that code by assigning an Integer to Number). In that case, don't instantiate Number, just do this instead:

```
Number myNumber = Integer.parseInt(userNumber.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Number is an abstract class, it means you have to implement it or use one of the already existing implementations.
So the code you wrote to us can became:

```
Integer myNumber = Integer.parseInt(userNumber.getText().toString());
```

Note:
I see you calling the methods *isTriangular()* and *isSquare()*, none of this are part of Number or Integer (and other numeric types in java).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the contributions, but the problem was a typo way earlier in the code.
The comments did help and I learned few key points.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You cannot instatiate Number wich is an abstact class. You should use one of this sub-classes : BigDecimal , BigInteger , Byte , Double , Float , Integer , Long , and Short.

And also the line

Number myNumber = new Number();

is totally useless,  you can directly declare and assign like this :

```
Number num = Integer.parseInt(userNumber.getText().toString());
```

Comment: He is using some sort of custom class that is also called Number, but also has a property that seems to be a Number.